# Flutter LinearProgressIndicator() issue

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I can't add border radius to linear progress indicator item. when trying add borderRadius as a parameter, it shows as error?

[Full snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DP7m.png)

[image: error]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqZBo.png)

How to fix this issue? Your help highly appreciated

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 2):

Remove Const Keyword before Linear Progress Indicator.
Because BorderRadius.circular invokes dynamic computation for painting border radius hence keyword const is making conflict there.

```
LinearProgressIndicator(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7))
```

OR below will do the same

```
 const LinearProgressIndicator(
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.green),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)))
```

If still the error persist try restarting dart analysis server by pressing refresh button at top left corner in android studio

[image]

Comment: . did it. still same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              value: controller.value,
              semanticsLabel: 'Linear progress indicator',
            ),
```